# Why were on-topic comments deleted?

Tags: discussion, comments

I had posted comments on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/8900730/684229

These comments were related to the code, noting that it is dangerous to use this replacement - in case the object has been already initialized, the new code is not equivalent to the old one, so special check is needed. This warning definitely would be useful to other users. I proposed the improvement to the author of the post.

May I ask who deleted the comments and why?

PS: my opinion is that comments should be taken more seriously and not routinely deleted as "too much trash". Many times people put effort and time in them, bring useful notes and comments. The approach "everything should be in the post" contradicts many other recommendations here on meta (discuss changes first, etc.).

Comment: There were **14** comments on that thread. Someone flagged the thread as something that needs to be purged and a moderator obliged them. I agree.

Comment: Also - comments are not supposed to be something that stays around forever. Comments can be deleted at any moment for any reason - if they are important enough, **they should be rolled into the post they are commenting on**.

Comment: @Oded, well, I can understand cleanup, but deleting everything, including relevant comments?

Comment: Yes. Moderators don't have time to sort the wheat from the chaff, and seeing the ephemeral nature of comments, it is much better use of their time to purge all the comments. I particular in a site as busy as Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Oded but we hammer into people that they shouldn't edit other people's code, and tell them to leave comments if they see something wrong. If the comment added important information, it arguably shouldn't have gone.

Comment: Oded, in another place on META it was discussed that changes should be discussed first by the owner of the post!!! The comments were removed *before* they could be rolled into the post!

Comment: @probablyPekka - Not disputing that, and I personally, will edit answers. I still don't quite get the community reaction to improving answers.

Comment: @Tomas - The OP probably disagreed with your comments. You are always free to post your own answer.

Comment: *"Moderators don't have time to sort the wheat from the chaff"* - if they don't have the time, they should probably leave the thread..

Comment: @Tomas - That's something that the moderator in question would need to consider. And, as someone who is not a moderator, I don't know that you can talk with authority on what moderators should and should not be doing.

Comment: @Oded, and if he disaggreed, then the comment should have stayed and discussed by my opinion, not purely deleted.

Comment: In a perfect world, @Tomas, in a perfect world...

Comment: If moderators routinely react to flags by indiscriminately deleting all of them, then we have a problem. That wasn't my understanding of how comment cleanup works.

Comment: @Oded but what about an answer that is *fundamentally* the wrong approach. There's no point in editing that into something completely different - a comment, and a downvote, is the only way to go. Most OPs don't change their answers when it is pointed out it has a fundamental flaw. If we have to expect now that mods delete even comments that point out a flaw, things are broken

Comment: @probablyPekka - when moderators see a very long comment thread, it can be far easier to simply purge the whole thing than pick out what is and is not relevant. Not saying this is right, but that this is what happens on occasion.

Comment: @probablyPekka, exactly, thanks. From point of view of user who has been here several years, I feel there is more and more of the machine-routine and less and less of the humanly approach...

Comment: I had exactly the same problem a week ago on Workplace http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/q/2161/6022 . Useful comment of other guy was deleted. Someone edited my question in such a way that it was completely different question, I didn't agree, but the change was enforced by moderators and post locked... These things didn't happen in the past as far as I remember...

Comment: @Tomas I have restored your single comment, in addition to the one the author wrote saying your suggestion is outside of the scope of the answer. How long they remain .. who knows. But, it did show that a point many would have was discussed. I still suggest adding your own answer to the question if you feel it's _really_ important.

Comment: Tomas, having just seen the posts that @TimPost restored, I think it would be a _really_ good idea if you deleted your comment in favor of one that didn't have the bold text and was generally toned down. I also think the idea of creating a separate answer was a good one, under the circumstances.

Comment: @Peter, OK, I toned it down. The reason why I put it in bold was that I considered this to be very important and users could fall into mistake very easily.

Comment: It was my answer and participation in an out-of-hand comment thread that sparked this.  And, once the comment conversation ended, _I was the one who flagged it._ Looking at my flag history, the message I used was "entire comment thread should probably be purged". What I _should have said_ was "a bunch of OT comments should be reviewed". I didn't wish for the whole thread to be deleted, because I _do_ think there were 3 or so relevant comments in there (those which were restored).

Comment: At the top of the comments had also been a handful of "thanks/me-too" which were not needed. So thanks to @TimPost for restoring the good ones judiciously.

Comment: And @Tomas thanks for bringing this to meta, because I'm glad to know that the mods are willing to spend a little time reviewing 3rd-class citizen comment threads.

Comment: @Tomas Comments are regarded as 2nd or 3rd class citizens, not your comments specifically, all comments; they are not usually regarded as lasting site content. That's why the mods are willing to remove them without much deliberation, and that's what brought you here.  "2nd class citizen or 3rd class citizen" is just the term often used on meta.

Comment: @meta.michael thanks. Your comment could have been explained differently. I will delete the question comment, you can delete the answer, just to make cleanup ourselves :)

Answer (score 4):

Comments are intended to be short ephemeral conversations that discuss the points of a parent post. They should not, under most circumstances, become lasting beacons alerting people to possible problems with the content of the parent post - because that would mean *that the change was never made*. That's an unsettled discussion lingering under an answer with no consensus - that's not useful.

In this case, the author of the post *specifically* said that he wasn't interested in incorporating your suggestions into his answer. At that point, your comments no longer served their designed purpose - the thing to have done is answer the question yourself where you could provide more clarity and explanation.

Once discussions look like they've served their purpose, and anything that is *going* to be changed in the parent post has been, they're subject to removal. That's what happened in this case, the conversation was clearly over - and there was little use in keeping it around.

Lasting information belongs in answers, and we're not going to relax that, we simply can't.
Part of our appeal is our *extremely high* signal to noise ratio, and we can't lose that.

***Per this specific conversation***

I have restored your comment, and the author's single reply stating that your suggestion is outside of the scope of the answer. I did that because you're *not* going to be the only one to suggest that, and this at least leaves evidence that the conversation was raised, in an effort to avoid duplicating what just happened all over again.

I stand by my answer, though - *anything* that is important needs to be put in *an* answer, whether it's the one that you feel needs correcting or one that you write yourself.

Comment: The author of the post stated that my change is *"different problem"* and refused to incorporate the suggestions. I respect his decision, but in that case, the added note (very much related to the topic) should have stayed at least as a comment.

Comment: @Tomas What I'm trying to explain is - comments aren't intended to become lasting beacons like that. The thing to have done is write your own answer, with what you felt was the correct information. The _only_ reason we added a comment feature was to curtail the use of answers asking for clarification - they should be considered _very_ temporary, they get automatically hidden when threads get long ... not the place to put something important :)

Comment: So what do you do if you see an accepted answer that promotes a bad practice?

Comment: *"our appeal is our extremely high signal to noise ratio"* - by deleting all comments which simply were not incorporated, **you loose a lot of signal**. And you start loosing my confidence in SO that my effort is valued. **There are plenty of posts here at so with *very* valuable comments, which helped me a lot many times!!** Thanks to SO for that, and I really think *we* can't lose that!

Comment: @probablyPekka Suggest the change, if not implemented then _edit it_ or add your own answer and edit the original to point you the one you wrote so it's noticed. If your comment is hidden, it doesn't help anyone.

Comment: So, Tim, if I understand you correctly, you're saying that the author of an answer has a right to arrange for a moderator to "clear all comments" if they think the comments don't "add value"? Is that right? If so, is that policy documented anywhere?

Comment: @PeterAlfvin There is no such policy. If a conversation in comments is flagged enough - moderators get notified. There's also an automatically raised system flag when enough comments appear in a post in a short amount of time. The post author has only the ability to ask a moderator to look. Moderators are not obligated to take any action.

Comment: @TimPost what if I can't post an answer because I don't know one - I just know the answerer's approach is really, really bad? I'm sure there are tens of thousands of comments of that nature in the system and they're super valuable. I'm sure I could dig up a quote from one of the Founding Fathers praising Stack Overflow exactly because experts leave comments on answers. I've always operated under the assumption that this content is going to survive most of the time, especially seeing as comments often don't trigger an action on the answerer's side.

Comment: @probablyPekka then go ahead and comment, just realize that it's _not_ going to be as helpful as someone correcting the answer, or writing a better one. Comments aren't permanent, they never were. Remember, moderators aren't even _needed_ to remove a comment if enough people flag it .. that's hardly an optimal place to put something important.

Comment: @TimPost Ok, well that's some comfort, at least. So this really comes down to moderators' attitudes towards comments in SO, which I assume varies quite a bit.

Comment: @Tim Fair enough - but if mods routinely don't take time *at all* to evaluate a comment thread before purging it, then the process is broken. They shouldn't be deleting comments at all then IMO.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin Unless a thread has just appeared to lose _all_ value, mods usually just prune comments (e.g. anything snarky, or "+1 wow great", or anything obsolete that has been addressed in the post). I can see why the mod just purged this one - it appeared to be a conversation that concluded, and the conclusion being nothing about the post was going to change as a result.

Comment: @TimPost I can understand your concern about mods not having the time to go through a long comment thread. Is it your view that if mods see at least some "inappropriate" comments in a thread, that they're justified in deleted the whole thread on the grounds that it's important to get rid of the whole thread and important not to consume too much mod time?

Comment: @TimPost *"Suggest the change, if not implemented then edit it"* - so when the author of the post doesn't want the suggested change, shall I just edit the post and **enforce it**? Is this policy documented somewhere?

Comment: @probablyPekka They _usually_ hold off if unsure, or just prune the obvious bits. I looked at all of the deleted comments and honestly, in this case, it looked like a dead-end conversation that wasn't going to change anything - I can see why the mod just purged instead.

Comment: @Tim ok cool. (I didn't see the conversation in question.)

Comment: @Tomas I was speaking in a general sense (I try to do that here, so that my posts are helpful to broader situations), where frequently the original author just isn't around any longer to notice the comment. As he clearly said he wasn't up for incorporating your change, the best thing to have done is add your own answer explaining why his was not as optimal as it could be.

Comment: @TimPost I'm still left with the sense that you think moderators should be responsive to author requests to remove comments they disagree with and aren't going to act upon, for the sake of keeping answers "clean". I can understand that perspective, but it makes for a very different SO than the one of gotten used to. Do you see SO making more serious moves in that direction (e.g. comments going away by themselves over time, etc.)?

Comment: @probablyPekka the conversation started by me noting the problem, then we discussed whether it should or should not be part of the answer. Unproductive discussion with lots of comments, I see why it was deleted - but the original comment on the problem should have been kept.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin Moderators should be responsive to _flags_ alerting them of things that _potentially_ require intervention. Note, I said responsive to _flags_, not necessarily the folks that raised them. Of course they need to _investigate_, that's their job. Action is at their discretion alone. Generally, though - 15+ comments usually indicates that things could be derailing, or might need a bit of pruning.

Comment: @Tomas I restored your comment, along with the author's indicating that he felt your suggestion was out of scope. See my edit. Those two comments remain useful because they stop the conversation / suggestion from happening all over again - which is why I restored them.

Comment: And as our Community user has now flagged my answer to indicate a swarm of comments has been posted in a short amount of time (oh, the irony), I bid you all good day :)

Answer (score -3):

Comments should never stay. The (re-)ordering and other properties of comments make them unsuitable for permanence. If you have something to say for the ages, write your own answer, or edit the answer to include your remarks. It's not reasonable to turn mods into winnowing machines trying to find kernels of truth amongst all the chaff.

Comment: I stay for my opinion - if mods don't have time to do this, they should leave the comments (probably only delete offensive ones, if that's the case). **The harm of deleting everything is bigger than the profit of the page "being clean"**. SO is well designed, users themselves can easily read or skip the comments and pick the most useful by voting on them.