# Moderator can delete my reply to his comment just because he wanted to delete his comment?

Tags: discussion, comments, moderators, deleted-comments

Strange thing occurred. User with moderator status pointed out something being wrong in my post. Only it wasn't really wrong, he just didn't read carefully, which I *politely* pointed out.

Having his confusion solved, he probably decided to delete the comment. But my comment would then make no sense. So he deleted it too.

Shouldn't he ask me first? I don't really like people going and deleting what I write. Anybody else could come up to that confusion (he wrongly copied URL in that case, which was *in that case* likely to happen).

This also had another side effect - it reduced *activity* that has happened on my question. It's about a bug in Markdown which I'd like to have fixed...

I decided not to go pointing fingers, even if I wanted to, moderator's name is gone along with the comments. Just tell me if this is normal and correct. And if you think it's normal and correct, definitely do not expect me to agree.

Comment: Yes, if comments achieved what was needed removing them is the correct thing to do. I would be thankful that the moderator removed all comments that were obsolete instead of only removing their own making look your comments all weird.

Comment: As you can see it can lead to confusion. You know, all my notifcations regrading the comment dissapeared, so did the record in my activity history. That can give one an creepy feeling.

Comment: Sure, but assume good faith.... specially on MSE that is moderated by SE employees...

Comment: "It's a bug in Markdown" - how does this have anything to do with Markdown?

Comment: @TomášZato something to think about: if it bothers you to have your contributions deleted without your explicit approval, you can always opt not to post comments. While it is possible to delete questions and answers (also without your approval), it pretty much only happens when the post is either truly terrible or actively harmful to the site.

Comment: "*Just tell me if this is normal and correct. And if you think it's normal and correct, definitely do not expect me to agree.*" Are we going on circles? What good would it do if we tell you that **it's normal**? Actually, obsolete removed comments are way better than comments that are left there and make no sense.

Comment: So much hate discourages me from further discussion.

Comment: @TomášZato I don't see any hate here, just people explaining to you that this is normal, and why it's not a problem.  That's not hate.

Comment: @TomášZato hate?  disagreement is not hate; and deleting a comment is very far from hate - that sounds unnecessarily melodramatic.

Comment: @TomášZato The comment was deleted because it was a discussion about a link and not about the post, _Once discussions look like they've served their purpose, and anything that is going to be changed in the parent post has been, they're subject to removal._ from [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/208689/275802)

Comment: After being answered, this question still keeps draining my reputation. That's what I call hate. I can't escape it. Even when browsing, I keep seeing negative numbers in recent reputation changes. This page in particular is very hateful and unforgiving in comparison to other SE sites.

Comment: [Voting is different on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta). Downvotes indicate disagreement and are not an expression of "hate." And meta.SE rep means nothing anyway.

Comment: The reputation determines your privileges, just like on any other site on SE. Sufficient amount of *disagreement* can ensure you can't even comment.

Comment: @TomášZato Actually, you can comment anywhere even with 1 reputation on meta (specifically for this reason). (sorry for late reply; didn't get an inbox notification)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, this is normal and correct.

As the Stack Exchange employee involved, I deleted the comments, as they were no longer relevant.

I pointed out that a link to a post was incorrect. It was. I ended up searching the site the issue was appearing on and fixing the link to the post myself.

---

Comments are not expected to be there for all eternity - we have always maintained that comments **can** and **will** disappear at any time without warning.

Comment: I now noticed that you were actually talking about different link.

Comment: Yes. I wasn't talking about the image at all. The link to the post was not working, as it was incorrect.

Comment: I hope you didn't mean to put "and **will**" in there.  Certainly some comments are useless and can be deleted.  But some comments supply useful additional information (or even correct answers that are just wrong), so it'd be really bad if all comments were to disappear at some point.

Comment: @pacoverflow - if a comment is so important, it should be edited **into** the post. At which point it would be obsolete and should be deleted.

Comment: @pacoverflow Quoting your comment 'or even correct answers that are just wrong', what is that supposed to mean?

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code I meant a wrong answer was posted, and a comment corrected it.

Comment: @pacoverflow In that case, the answer itself should be deleted (along with its comments).

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code Yes, or the answer should be edited. But sometimes the person who posted the answer doesn't agree with the commenter - I don't see why else they wouldn't edit their answer.