# Why doesn't the username in mentions not get auto-edited when the original one does?

Tags: discussion, bug, comments, display-names, comment-replies

I used to go by "d4rk4ng31" (um, as you might have already guessed, silly teenage years) which then I changed (long back, but I just noticed this as I am not a very active member anymore). I see that it has changed everywhere I was an author:

[image: comment]

but not where I was "mentioned":

[image: mention]

---

Is this intended design? I don't see any practical use case in which it is.

Comment: This is definitely not a [tag:bug]. It's [tag:status:bydesign]. There have been multiple [tag:feature-request] questions over the years asking for `@` mentions in comments to be updated upon the pinged user's username being changed.

Comment: The comment is just stored as the full text at the time it was written, including any `@` mentions in plain text. Not with some token placeholder that will always be replaced dynamically with your _current_ username. This would be quite a bit more expensive to render, given that a large portion of comments have `@` mentions, and probably a small portion of users change their display name. So the benefit of rendering it dynamically is pretty low. Also remember comments are supposed to be temporary - if a comment is useful, it should be worked into the post. So again value is low.

Comment: @AaronBertrand While I understand that it can be seen as low value to change those under many conditions, there are conditions under which it's high value to change `@` mentions. Continuing to have those mentions around can feel like [deadnaming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadnaming) to the person being mentioned. While it's not someone using the dead name in *new* situations, it can have a similar impact on the person mentioned, which can be quite significant.

Comment: Some useful background [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208683/165455) and note there have even been feature requests to make comments automatically disappear [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7738/165455) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182295/165455).

Comment: @Makyen retrofitting all comments to support this type of dynamic replacement would be a monumental task, and something that isn’t even done for `@` mentions in more permanent objects like questions and answers. I’m not saying the value is _zero_, just that it’s very low relative to the work required _and_ performance forever. In the extreme case where, say, a popular question with a lot of traffic mentions your old username, there are options like flagging for moderator attention (who can delete the comment or modify it long after grace period). Or the contact link to get more elaborate help.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Yes, doing it dynamically would be quite significant. That's not how I was envisioning handling it. It seems like it could be implemented reasonably easily by keeping the comments as text, just as they are, without dynamic replacement, so no performance hit on pages. Upon a user changing their username, a task could update the text in the relatively few comments which the database indicates as having a mention for the user (and an edit indicator shown, so just a new revision). While there are complications to changing the text, they are surmountable.

Comment: @AaronBertrand You might want to reply to [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/396606/377214) with this info, then. Basically, they cite the fact that the system saves the user to whom a comment replies as "evidence" that it's an easier-done process than what it's made out to be (to me, it's not even so, since @-mentions can be anywhere and editing a whole lot of comments would increase system load quite a bit).

Comment: @AaronBertrand Yes, updating the `@` mentions is something that moderators can do. I've seriously considered writing a userscript to automatically update all of the mentions of a user to their new username both on the main sites and in chat. However, it would be much better if it was something the system supported being done, even if it was only done upon a user asking for it via "Contact Us", rather than a user needing to individually ask a moderator on each site they've used to make those changes.

Comment: @Makyen "update the text in the relatively few comments which the database indicates as having a mention for the user" I think the point is that the database does not store that information.  But I am not sure.

Comment: @Makyen Yes, as a DBRE I can at least partially envision how such a _one-time_ change could be made, at least per site. Across the whole network for a given user would be harder, unless they made the exact same username changes everywhere. But that's a different feature request altogether; this question seems to just lament that this doesn't automatically _always happen_. My comments were mostly trying to explain some of the practical reasons why this isn't how the system works today.

Comment: (And I didn't even consider, until reading the other answers on the duplicate, that (1) conversations can include more than one user with the same `@handle`, since they aren't unique; and, (2) short forms of handles can also be present (e.g. `@Aaron` instead of `@AaronBertrand`). These do certainly complicate any ability to do this - in real time, upon username change, or retroactively upon request.)